# I am not able to use .htaccess for beautify the URL of my website

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am working on website. I am new with .htaccess, I want to use it for removing category?cid=1/2/3/...so on, from my URL :- http://localhost/Aabhushnam/category?cid=1 but after writing the .htaccess rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)$ category/?cid=$1 [L]
```

and refreshing the page I am getting same thing with this url "http://localhost/Aabhushnam/category?cid=1" that's ok, but while changing the URL to http://localhost/Aabhushnam/category/1

I am getting an error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server."

`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]` this rule is working its removes .php from my URL's.

Any help?

Comment: Could you please do mention which URL you are hitting on browser with example and what it should become in browser then? That will help us to understand your question in better manner, thank you

Comment: after writing this **(RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)$ category/?cid=$1 [L])** rule in .htaccess and hitting this **(http://localhost/Aabhushnam/category/1)**  i am getting 404 error in my browser **The requested URL was not found on this server.** @RavinderSingh13

Comment: OK thanks for info. URL `Aabhushnam/category/1` should be served from which file in backend? Please confirm once.

Comment: in your rewrite rule you begin with ^ wich means the urls muste begin with category
in your exemple : there's a parent directory (Aabhushnam) can you try without ^ in the rule ?

Comment: I think we have some communication gap...sry for that I want my url this  **http://localhost/Aabhushnam/category?cid=1** to look like  **http://localhost/Aabhushnam/category/1** for which I am using rule **RewriteRule ^category/([0-9]+)$ category/?cid=$1 [L]** but after hitting this **http://localhost/Aabhushnam/category/1** I am getting error **The requested URL was not found on this server."** @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @R.Martin Ok let me try and inform you.

Comment: its not working same error @R.Martin